# MYSQL: comparing a NULL date to CURRENT_DATE

Tags: mysql, date

I have a MYSQL table with news articles with the fields "date_start" and "date_end" to indicate which news to show on a web site. Articles are public if date_start is before today and the date_end hasn't already gone by (after today).

The problem:
I'd like to let the admin leave date_end NULL if the article is of permanent nature and doesn't expire. This of course doesn't work with my select:

```
 SELECT * FROM pf_news WHERE date_start <= CURRENT_DATE() AND date_end >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

It leaves out articles with a `NULL date_end`. I tried playing a bit with IF statements but it got confusing for me. Is there a simple way of doing this, or should I just set date_end to `3000-01-01` if it's left empty? :)

Answer (score 28):

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM pf_news WHERE date_start <= CURRENT_DATE() AND 
(date_end >= CURRENT_DATE() OR date_end IS NULL)
```

or some similar logical grouping.

Comment: Thanks guys for the amazingly fast replies! This one does absolutely what i was looking. It was finally quite easy :)

Answer (score 4):

Your last proposal sounds correct.  You can use the IFNULL function.  It has two arguments.  If the first argument is non-null, it returns the first argument.  The second argument is what to return if the first argument is null.  So in your statement, you can say this:

```
SELECT * FROM pf_news WHERE date_start <= CURRENT_DATE() AND IFNULL(date_end, '3000-01-01') >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

This can also be used in SQL Server, but they call it the "ISNULL" function.

Just set a calendar reminder for yourself on 12/31/2999 to change  your code!  :)

Comment: I realized this one is a bit of a hack as it would show the site admin the 3000-01-01 date in the edit form :)

Comment: Because the IFNULL statement is only in the WHERE clause rather thant the SELECT clause, then the '3000-01-01' shouldn't ever be returned as a query result.  At least, this has worked well for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

From the little i got your question you want one  of this

A] date_end more than current date or if it is null

```
SELECT * FROM pf_news 
         WHERE date_start <= CURRENT_DATE() AND (date_end >= CURRENT_DATE() OR date_end IS NULL )
```

B] date_end must be present and more than current date

```
SELECT * FROM pf_news 
         WHERE date_start <= CURRENT_DATE() AND
               date_end >= CURRENT_DATE()   AND 
               date_end IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: "IS NULL" not "IS NIL" in MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

or try

```
SELECT * FROM pf_news WHERE date_start <= now() AND (date_end >= now() OR date_end = 0)
```

0 seems to work just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Yet an other possibility is using COALESCE, it returns the first non null value of a list:

```
SELECT * FROM pf_news WHERE date_start <= CURRENT_DATE() AND 
COALESCE(date_end,'9999-1-1') >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

So if `date_end` is NULL the future date '9999-1-1' will be used inside the comparison.
But this will break after this date :-)