# Mysql query WHERE clause not working. WHERE useDate<>CURDATE()

Tags: mysql, sql, date

`useDate` is date type and is `NULL`.
The query below doesn't work

```
UPDATE licenses 
     SET useDate = CURDATE() 
WHERE license = 'ABC123' AND useDate <> CURDATE();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL: comparing a NULL date to CURRENT\_DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149633/mysql-comparing-a-null-date-to-current-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL 101: `NULL` is not equal to anything. Likewise, `NULL` is not not-equal to anything. Use `IS NULL` in such situations:

```
UPDATE licenses
SET useDate = CURDATE()
WHERE license = 'ABC123' AND (useDate IS NULL OR useDate <> CURDATE());
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the `where` clause -- `NULL` values don't match `<>` or `=`. You can do:

```
UPDATE licenses 
     SET useDate = CURDATE() 
WHERE license = 'ABC123' AND
      (useDate <> CURDATE() or useDate IS NULL);
```

Or use MySQL's NULL-safe comparison:

```
UPDATE licenses 
     SET useDate = CURDATE() 
WHERE license = 'ABC123' AND
      NOT (useDate <=> CURDATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

convert `date`  and use `Trim` on license column in case of any blank space

```
UPDATE licenses 
         SET useDate = date(now())
    WHERE Trim(license) = 'ABC123' AND date(useDate)!= date(now());
```

Answer (score 0):

could be you have a datetime for useDate

```
    UPDATE licenses 
         SET useDate = CURDATE() 
    WHERE license = 'ABC123' AND date(useDate) != CURDATE();
```

so you need  to compare the date part

Answer (score 0):

That request worked for me ;)

```
UPDATE licenses 
SET useDate = CURDATE() 
WHERE license = 'ABC123' AND (useDate IS NULL OR useDate <> CURDATE());
```